# How do I stop GraphQL queries from being displayed in browser developer tools? The GraphQL query is dispalyed under payload

Tags: browser, graphql, nestjs, developer-tools

Is there a setting or a work-around for me to stop GraphQL queries from being displayed in browser developer tools? In Chrome, my GraphQL queries are listed under the "Payload" tab in the "Network" section. It is a full query that works if I copied and pasted it then sent the request using Postman or in the Playground with the right data.

[image: Found thru Developer Tools (F12) -> Network -> Fetch/XHR]

When I check FaceBook, I don't see a full usable query written out. The shape is not visible.

[image: FaceBook viewed using the same method as the first image.]

Comment: any reason why you want to not display it in developer tools?

Comment: It's a request from the website owners. The owners have a separate security team. They decided that displaying the whole readable mutations/queries and their shape was a security risk.

Comment: *any* request triggered by the browser will be visible on the network tab. It doesn't matter if it is REST or GraphQL. The only thing you could do is to encrypt the data you are passing to the endpoint. on your facebook example if you filter by graphql instead of relay-ef you can see the queries are visible also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of June 2023, it is still not possible to hide the GraphQL query structure and parameters from a browser's dev. tools. This is a screenshot of my Facebook page:
[image]

Marco Daniel's comment in 2022 is still true.